# Space error in sirius

Tags: modeling, xtext, eclipse-sirius

I created my xtext grammar, and now I use sirius to model, the problem I have is when I create an element from the palette (eg I create a button), In the file that takes the extension of the xtext in my case 'instance.pfe' I find a space error, the space given by modeling is not the same in the grammar .
I did not understand where this error came from , And how to solve it, thank you for helping me.

this is an example
[image: this is an example]

[My grammar](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ssFK_TRgkoaQloAqR4JO6OR4z0GgFfyXC3lnnkbOtuU/edit)

Comment: How does the grammar look like? Did you implement the formatter?

Comment: No I have not implemented the formatter ..

Maybe that's the mistake , I saw on the internet that I have to activate it !!  But i have no idea about its implementation ??

Comment: No but depending on you grammar and the way you edit the model the formatter and or parser may do wired things or have a bug. This is why I was asking for a small reproducible grammar

Comment: I modified my question by inserting my grammar..

Comment: The link to your grammar doesn't work for me. I can't access without having a Google account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not make use of spaces inside keywords. this will have all kinds of wired sideeffects like the one you are facing.

so insteadof using

```
SomeRule: 'somekeyword : ' somevalue=INT
```

you should use

```
SomeRule: 'somekeyword' ':'  somevalue=INT
```

if you really want to enforce a space then introduce a terminal for it

```
terminal SPACE: ' ';

SomeRule: 'somekeyword' SPACE ':' SPACEsomevalue=INT
```

Update:to enable class splitting

```
        parserGenerator = {
            options = {
                classSplitting = true
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes I used the notation 'SomeRule: 'somekeyword' ':'  somevalue=INT' before changing it to the current one but I always had the same problem when I slide a button for example, in the text file of the model I find an error, it inserts a space that it Is not found in the grammar for more detail:
'text' ':' text1=textType ';'
Sirius inserts a space between 'text' and ':' ...... in other cases it removes this space.... I do not understand why ??

Comment: Yes but if you do your grammar right it will work with and without space

Comment: => why is there an error with the space is the thing to be looked at

Comment: Ok so I will rewrite my grammar with a fixed syntax and I will see if the error disappears ......thank you very much Sir.

Comment: I changed my grammar and fixed a syntax but now I have an error when i generate Xtext Artifacts as follows:
The code for the static initializer is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit.

Comment: Have a look at class method splitting in the options in (possibly to be added ) parserGenerator={...} in the language section

Comment: I understood that there is no space in the grammar file but I can't remove any rules I have to put them all ,is what there is a method, Can be split a part in an external file or another solution...... thank you for helping me

Comment: Ok I'll pick this class now

Comment: p.s.: which is the java class you get the error about?

Comment: p.s: and make sure you really dont have any spaces in keywords. (there is a warning for that in xtext 2.11+)

Comment: I changed the file that takes the extension (.mwe2) I replaced the following line: 'fragment = parser.antlr.XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment' by: fragment = parser.antlr.XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment auto-inject {
                Options = {
                    // backtrack = true
                    ClassSplitting = true
                    MethodsPerClass = "100"
                    FieldsPerClass = "100"
                }
            }
And the problem is solved, and now I will test it in sirius if there is always the space problem or not.